# Why does programmatically checking a checkbox cause its associated event to fire on the next postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've reduced my problem to the simplest form possible since I'm working on a very complicated page.  This example has a set of dynamically generated checkboxes.  Some of these checkboxes may need to be checked when the page first loads.  Also, an event needs to fire whenever a box is checked or unchecked. There is also a drop down list that needs to autopostback when the selected index is changed.  The problem is that if I programmatically check a check box then the checkbox event will fire when I make a selection on the drop downlist. To recreate the bug/issue put a break-point on the checkbox event and on the drop down list event.  Load the page and make a selection from the drop down list.  The checkbox event will fire before the drop down list event.  If you look at the sender of the checkbox event it is the checkbox that was programmatically checked when the page was initialized. If the drop down list is changed I only want the drop down event to fire, but I still need to programmatically check a check box when the page is loaded the first time.

```
 <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="DropDownList1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers> 
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
            <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" >
                <asp:ListItem Text="--Select--" Value="0" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" Value="2" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        CreateCheckboxes();
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        InitializeCheckboxes();
    }
}

protected void CheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CheckBox cb = sender as CheckBox;
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Do Something
}

private void InitializeCheckboxes()
{
    Table tbl = new Table();

    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "cb_" + x.ToString();
        cb.Text = "cb_" + x.ToString();
        cb.AutoPostBack = true;
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);

        if (x == 2)
            cb.Checked = true;

        tc.Controls.Add(cb);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    }

    tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
}

private void CreateCheckboxes()
{
    Table tbl = new Table();

    TableRow tr = new TableRow();

    for (int x = 1; x <= 3; x++)
    {
        TableCell tc = new TableCell();
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.ID = "cb_" + x.ToString();
        cb.Text = "cb_" + x.ToString();
        cb.AutoPostBack = true;
        cb.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(CheckBox_CheckedChanged);

        tc.Controls.Add(cb);
        tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    }

    tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(tbl);
}
```

Comment: why are you initializing them and adding them(checkboxes) again??

Comment: That's an ugly rectangle of text you have at the top of your question

Comment: The checkboxes are dynamically generated so they will disappear if they are not re-added with each postback.

Comment: Why not change the markup to initialize the second check box as checked = true?

Comment: The checkboxes and whether they need to be checked is dependent on database values.

Answer (score 0):

Selected index changed because you have it wired up to do so

`OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged"`

Again check box changed fires because you heve unchecked it so it has changed from checked to unchecked. If you want to stop the handler doing anything check its state and return if its unchecked.

**UPDATE**

> The problem is that if I programmatically check a check box then the
>   checkbox event will fire when I make a selection on the drop downlist

I think this is expected behavior, it's similar to what would happen if you manually checked a bunch of check boxes then changed a ddl with autopostback set to true, it will process all the events.  Can you explain your problem in an abstract sense, what are you trying to achieve, why don't you want the check box events to fire, you have after all created them and then checked them so therefore the event fires?

You could do some nasty hacking to unwire the checkbox events in Page_load and wire them back in the LoadComplete.  You could possibly use the IsCallback property, but this would only work in your simple example because you ddl is in an update panel.

I would suggest not using server side events at all.  Create a web service and use something like jQuery ajax to post all the relevant data to it that is required to carry out the work.

Comment: I want "DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" to fire when the drop down is changed. The problem is that "CheckBox_CheckedChanged" is firing when the drop down is changed if I programmatically check a checkbox and it's the first postback after page load.

Comment: The problem is that CheckBox_CheckChanged is firing when I make a selection on the drop down list.  I edited the question so hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: The purpose of the page is for line supervisors to record their scrap in a manufacturing plant.  The check boxes represent alternate departments to charge scrap. If one of the alt. depts. is checked then I must display different controls on the page.  I'm running into the problem on edit when I must load the page with values populated.  Making changes on other controls (like drop downs) is causing the checkedchanged event to fire.  I would like to programmatically check the checkbox but suppress that event. I'd be happy with a hack at this point, otherwise I'll have to redesign that section.

Comment: This is basically the last thing I need to get working before this application, which I have been working on for several months, is complete.  So re-designing isn't my favorite option at this point.